# Parsing the style.filter string using javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, css

I'm trying to get some filter properties of a DOM element, such as opacity, blur, etc. At the moment I'm splitting the string and then trying to match the string tokens against known filter types using regex. My question:

I'm having trouble with the logical OR in the regex below - I'm trying to match "opacity(0.234) or opacity(1)" for example.

```
var re1="(opacity)";    // word "opacity"
var re2="(\\()";    // single character '('
var re3 = "(0(\.\d+)?)" //0, with possible decimals after
var re4 = "(1)" //single character '1'
var re3or4 = "("+re3+"|"+re4+")"; //logical or
var re5 = "(\\))";  //single character ')'
var reg = new RegExp(re1+re2+re3or4+re5, "i");

//unit tests
console.log(reg.test("opacity(0)")); //true
console.log(reg.test("opacity(0.4)")); //true
console.log(reg.test("opacity(1)")); //true
console.log(reg.test("opacity()")); //false
console.log(reg.test("opacity")); //false
```

1. What have I screwed up? (It's returning false on most tests where it should be true)
2. Is there a better way (i.e. a way to access the various constituent parts of the filter string with object notation or something similar)? Parsing strings to fish out properties is painful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to double `\` everywhere. Also, there is no point of overusing capturing groups, I suggest removing them and replacing with non-capturing ones so as not to cluster the match object.

Here are the changes I suggest:

```
var re1="opacity";    // word "opacity"
var re2="\\(";    // single character '('
var re3 = "0(?:\\.\\d+)?" //0, with possible decimals after 
//             ^^ ^^ 
var re4 = "1" //single character '1'
var re3or4 = "("+re3+"|"+re4+")"; //logical or
var re5 = "\\)";  //single character ')'
var reg = new RegExp(re1+re2+re3or4+re5, "i"); // => /opacity\((0(?:\.\d+)?|1)\)/i
```

```js
var re1="opacity";    // word "opacity"
var re2="\\(";    // single character '('
var re3 = "0(?:\\.\\d+)?" //0, with possible decimals after
var re4 = "1" //single character '1'
var re3or4 = "("+re3+"|"+re4+")"; //logical or
var re5 = "\\)";  //single character ')'
var reg = new RegExp(re1+re2+re3or4+re5, "i"); // => /opacity\((0(?:\.\d+)?|1)\)/i

console.log(reg);
  //unit tests
console.log(reg.test("opacity(0)")); //true
console.log(reg.test("opacity(0.4)")); //true
console.log(reg.test("opacity(1)")); //true
console.log(reg.test("opacity()")); //false
console.log(reg.test("opacity")); //false
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Do you recommend extracting css filter values this way though, or is there a better, more appropriate way to do it?

Comment: I am no expert in css filters, but if it is plain text and there are no nested constructions, you can use regex to extract whatever you need.

Comment: I decided to accept this answer because it seems no-one else has a suggestion of a way to access the various filter parameters directly.

Answer (score 1):

For reference of anyone else hoping to do the same thing, here's a code template. I'm still looking for a more elegant way of accessing the parameters' values directly because this is ugly.

```
//example properties with default values
    var properties = {
    "sepia": 0, 
    "saturate": 1, 
    "opacity": 1
    //add your own...
}

//set up the regex
var re2 = "\\(";    // single character '('
var re3 = ".*"; //match any character multiple times 
var re5 = "\\)";  //single character ')'

//parse the values
var el = document.getElementById("blah");
var filterStrings = el.style.filter.split(" "); //generate array of filter property strings
for(var p in properties){
    if(properties.hasOwnProperty(p)){
        //loop through all the filter strings and see if we have a match with current property p
        for(var i = 0; i < filterStrings.length; i++){
            //construct regular expression based on current property p
            var reg = new RegExp(p+re2+re3+re5, "i");
            if(reg.test(filterStrings[i])){
                //if we have a match, strip the filter name and save the value
                properties[p] = filterStrings[i].replace(p,'').replace('(','').replace(')','');
            }
        }
    }
}
```